# Mixing Orchard CMS content with module

Tags: orchardcms

I am currently working on an Orchard module. This module contains an MVC application including the views. I would like to make the module as configurable as possible. One of the items that I would like the customer to configure is the way the MVC views from the module look. Part of it will be determined by the theme. But not everything. Consider the following scenario:

The module contains a view for placing an order. The view displays a form in ´normal view way´. That is field labels and input labels. But at the head of the form each customer must be able to define his own set of instructions to display. Or maybe the customer wants to put there a message for pointing the customer to some other actions.

In the most ideal way I would have a content page where the customer can put all kind of content and one specific block that is the result of the view of the module. Kind like a web part. I can´t find out if it is possible and how that is achieved.

**Edit for clarification**
Module creates a page like this:

TITLE
FORM

So both title and form are outputted by the module controller.

I have managed to create a layer with the condition that the url matches the page with my form.

I have added a HTML widget to this layer in the content zone with position 1 (tried 0 to).

However the pages looks like this:

- TITLE
- FORM
- WIDGET

instead of

- WIDGET
- TITLE
- FORM

Answer (score 1):

Returning a ShapeResult from your controller action will ensure that your view is themed and benefits from widgets, which are your "kind like a web part" thingies in Orchard.

Comment: Thank you Bertrand. But I am not sure if that is the answer I am looking for. Let me try: I have a module, with one of the functionalities to create an order. I should then create a widget where the shaperesult of the order create action is rendered. Then I should define a widget that only appears on one page. the order creation page. I don't know if that is what I am looking for. I will clarify in the question. If the answer remains the same then I will dig further into that.

Comment: I think I understand now what you mean. Let me know if I have understood correctly. I would render a view from my module containg the form with the bare necessities. I would then for instance create HTML widgets in Orchard itself and place those on a new layer (the layer that only applies to the page where the form is created)

Comment: Yes. There is an alternative however. From your controller action, you can get hold of the Layout object through a IWorkContextAccessor. Then, you can create new shapes and inject those into top-level zones. See http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/26/dispatching-orchard-shapes-to-arbitrary-zones.aspx for more details about this technique. I think this is closer to what you're looking for.